# How to merge multiple values in a same dictionary?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, indexing

I have two dictionaries `x` and `y`, which consist of keys and values.

`x` (its 'values') showing the address (which I want to merge in `y`).

`y` represents the dictionary whose 'values', I want to merge.

For example:  `x = { 1: [1,2], ...}` i.e.,   I want to merge 1st and 2nd  'values' of  `y` dictionary.

So desired output will be `[0,1,2,3]`.

Similarly for `4:[2,5]`  it is `[2,3,29,30,31]`.

Is it possible to do this operation in python and finally brought this result into a separate list for each value of `y`?

```
x = { 1:[1,2], 2:[2,3], 3:[3,4], 4:[2,5]} 

y = { 1:[0,1], 2:[2,3], 3:[4,5], 4:[6,7], 5:[29,30,31]  }
```

**Desired output:**

```
[0,1,2,3]
[2,3,4,5]
[4,5,6,7]
[2,3,29,30,31]
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with nested loops over the values in `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One-liner**

```
my_list = [[j for s in x[i] for j in y[s]] for i in x]
```

**Longer but perhaps more readable**

```
x = {1: [1,2], 2: [2,3], 3: [3,4], 4: [2,5]}

y = {1: [0,1], 2: [2,3], 3: [4,5], 4: [6,7], 5: [29,30,31]}

my_list = []

for i in x:
    temp = []
    my_list.append(temp)
    for j in x[i]:
        temp.extend(y[j])

print(my_list)
```

For complicated list comprehensions I prefer explicitly writing out loops for improved readability. Whether one snippet is more readable than another is of course a matter of opinion.

**Output**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 29, 30, 31]]
```

I hope it helps. If there are any questions or if this is not what you wanted, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You actually only need one line:

```
[sum([y[index] for index in v], start=[]) for k, v in x.items()]
```

This gives:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 29, 30, 31]]
```

If you want to print all of the sub-lists:

```
for k, v in x.items():
    print(sum([y[index] for index in v], start=[]))
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 29, 30, 31]
```

Comment: thankyou for the reply sir, but here it is showing the  `TypeError: sum() takes no keyword arguments`